# Pipe character URL encoding issue

Tags: django, django-templates, urlencode

I am using URL encoding for my links in a Django template smoothly for all sorts of characters in the link so far. However, today I faced a problem with encoding of the pipe (|) character.

When a pipe character was encoded, I saw the URL appeared with `"%7C"` (it is correct).

This part of the encoding was for parameter passing through HTTP GET, which I display as part of a title. However, the title rendered is `","`.

Here's the full cycle:

1. `A = "|x|"`
2. Passed `{{A|urlencode}}` will give the URL phrase as `"%7Cx%7C"`
3. `"%7Cx%7C"` decoded to the title as `",x,"`.

What is the reason?